# Bash script answer automatically command

Tags: bash, git, shell, automation, command-prompt

In a sh script I tried push file automatically, but when you do "git pull" the repository ssh via and then in "git push" command ask me:

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is 11:00:22:33:44:55:66:77:88:99:10:11:12:13:14:15.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I tried this:

```
echo "yes\n" | git push
```

---

```
git push << EOF
yes
EOF
```

---

```
yes "yes" | git push
```

---

```
printf '%s\n' yes | git push
```

but doesn't work, I don't know if this command works different

Comment: @johnny243 I solved adding to ssh config file  `Host gitlab.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking no`, this ignores the ssh key validation.

Comment: Don't add answers to the question, create an actual answer instead. Self-answering is totally fine.